# Exchange 2010 address location

Tags: active-directory, exchange, powershell, exchange-2010

Can someone tell me where Exchange 2010 stores e-mail address information?  Has it moved from the proxyAddresses attribute in ActiveDirectory?  Does "(Get-Mailbox).EmailAddresses" give the same info as "Get-AdUser -Propery proxyAddresses"?  I've tried looking this up, but just keep getting links to different invocations of "Get-Mailbox" or "Get-Recipient".  I'd like to keep this script simple and not require the Exchange tools to be installed if I don't have to.

Comment: AFAIK, they're still stored in the proxyAddresses attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just checked that on two different Exchange 2010 production servers. Users email address information is still stored in proxyAddresses property.

```
Get-ADUser -filter * -properties ProxyAddresses | ft proxyaddresses
```

Comment: I'd come to the same conclusion.  I can't find anything else that has the actual mail addresses in it, so it must be stored in that one.  Thanks.  :-)